# Rails, Bootstrap and and enum dropdown - value not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm working already a while on that playing around but it doesn't work for me: 
I got an enum dropdown and want to use bootstrap for the front end.

```
enum show_email: {all: 1, buddies: 2, private: 3 }, _prefix: true
```

my form code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :show_email, class: "col-sm-1 col-form-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <%= select_tag :show_email, options_for_select(User.show_emails.keys.map {|k, v| [k.humanize.capitalize, v]}), class: "form-control", 'data-style': 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It shows the dropdown nicely but doesn't save the data.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but you could shorten your collection with this : `User.show_emails.map { |k,v| [k.humanize.capitalize,v] }` I would use this with Rajdeep's answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `f.select` instead of `select_tag` as `show_email` is part of the model

```
<%= f.select :show_email, options_for_select(User.show_emails.keys.map {|k, v| [k.humanize.capitalize, v]}), {}, { class: "form-control", 'data-style': 'form-control' } %>
```

Give it a try

Comment: This worked for me:
<%= f.select :show_email, User.show_emails.keys.to_a, {},  { class: "form-control", 'data-style': 'form-control' } %>